# How to draw the next pictures?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I need to draw the following pictures, but I am new in latex, can anybody help me?. Thank you[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please accept one of the provided answers if your question was answered.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the following could give you a start, then you just have to adapt the code for every modulo you want:
[image: modulo made visual]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\tikzset{dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt,fill=black}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\r{3}
        \node[draw=blue,circle,fill=cyan,minimum size=\r cm] {8 mod 4 = 0};
        \foreach \i in {0,1,...,8}
            {
            \pgfmathsetmacro\im{int(\i/4)}
            \node[dot] (p\i) at (90-\i*90:.75*\r+\im*.5){};
            \ifnum\i<4
                \node at (90-\i*90:.65*\r){\i};
            \fi
            \ifnum\i>0
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\i-1}
                \draw (p\j.center) to[bend left,looseness=1.5] (p\i.center);        
            \fi
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT: an alternate version using `to[out=...,in=...]`

[image: modulo made visual V2]

You can play with the `looseness` to get nice "square" curves.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\tikzset{dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt,fill=black}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\r{3}
        \node[draw=blue,circle,fill=cyan,minimum size=\r cm] {8 mod 4 = 0};
        \foreach \i in {0,1,...,8}
            {
            \pgfmathsetmacro\im{int(\i/4)}
            \node[dot] (p\i) at (90-\i*90:.75*\r+\im*.5){};
            \ifnum\i<4
                \node at (90-\i*90:.65*\r){\i};
            \fi
            \ifnum\i>0
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\i-1}
                \pgfmathsetmacro\imod{Mod(\i,4)}
                \draw[olive] (p\j) to[out=-\imod*90+90,in=-\imod*90+180,looseness=1.5] (p\i);       
            \fi
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried to make the second figure, but I couldn't, it looks very different

Answer (score 3):

In my proposal I made a macro that makes the division if you provide the numbers (and the position of the figure). It needs a lot of "programming" (`\foreach`, `\ifnum`, etc.), but I think that it's worth doing it because then you can draw all the divisions you need.

This is what I have:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Definitions
\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{C8C7FF}
\def\cr{1.25} % circle radius
\def\dr{0.05} % dot radius

\newcommand{\division}[3] % #1 mod #2 (#2 > 0), #3 -> position
{% #1 = q * #2 + r
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\p{abs(#1)}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\s{#1 < 0 ? 1 : -1} % sign
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\q{\p/#2}           % quotient
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\r{Mod(#1,#2)}      % residue
  \begin{scope}[shift={#3}, x={(0 cm,1 cm)}, y={(\s cm, 0 cm)}]
    \draw[fill=myblue] (0,0) circle (\cr) node {$#1 \bmod #2 = \r$};
    \foreach\i in {1,...,#2}
    {% first turn of dots (mandatory, we are drawing all the labels)
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\i-1}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\an{-360*\j/#2}                 % angle
      \pgfmathsetmacro\nr{2.25*\cr+0.25*\j*\cr/#2}    % radius
      \pgfmathsetmacro\n{#1*\j >= 0 ? \j : int(#2-\j)} % node label
      \coordinate (n\j) at (\an:\nr);
      \node at (\an:2*\cr) {$\n$};
      \fill (n\j) circle (\dr);
    }
    \foreach\i in {1,...,\p}
    {% rest of the turns of dots and all the edges
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\i-1}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\an{-360*\i/#2}              % angle
      \pgfmathsetmacro\nr{2.25*\cr+0.25*\i*\cr/#2} % radius
      \unless\ifnum\i < #2 % if it isn't drawn in the first turn
        \coordinate (n\i) at (\an:\nr);
        \fill (n\i) circle (\dr);
      \fi
      \draw (n\j) to[bend left=-180*\s/#2+10*\s] (n\i);
    }
  \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \division{ 8}{4}{( 0,8)}
  \division{ 7}{2}{( 7,8)}
  \division{-5}{3}{(14,8)}
  \division{11}{5}{( 0,0)}
  \division{ 1}{3}{( 7,0)}
  \division{-9}{3}{(14,0)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Great solution. I just didn't want to do all the job, but well... you did ! ;)

Comment: @SebGlav, thanks!! It's not so different form yours. I only wrapped all inside a macro and prepared it so that it takes into account if the divisor is negative or not. But essentially we have the same idea.